# Removing values from categorical variables

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
  summary(imputedWork)
              everwrk          age_p      
 1 Yes            :27918   Min.   :18.00  
 2 No             : 5034   1st Qu.:33.00  
 7 Refused        :   45   Median :47.00  
 8 Not ascertained:    0   Mean   :48.11  
 9 Don't know     :   17   3rd Qu.:62.00  
                           Max.   :85.00  

                            r_maritl    
 1 Married - spouse in household:13943  
 7 Never married                : 7763  
 5 Divorced                     : 4511  
 4 Widowed                      : 3069  
 8 Living with partner          : 2002  
 6 Separated                    : 1121  
 (Other)                        :  605
```

I want to remove the "Refused", "Don't Know", and "Not ascertained" values from everwrk and the "(Other)" values from r_maritl.

Answer (score 1):

This will drop the row when match with the value you do not need

```
 A=c("Refused","Don't Know", "Not ascertained")
 B=c("Married - spouse in household",
    "Never married","Divorced","Widowed","Living with partner","Separated")
 imputedWork[!imputedWork$everwrk %in% A & imputedWork$r_maritl %in% B,]
```

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr`solution:

```
imputedWork <- imputedWork %>% 
  filter(
    (everwrk=="Yes" | everwrk=="No") & r_maritl!="(Other)"
  )
```

If `everwrk` and `r_maritl` are `factor`, you'll also want to drop the levels:

```
imputedWork <- imputedWork %>% 
  filter(
    (everwrk=="Yes" | everwrk=="No") & r_maritl!="(Other)"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(everwork=droplevels(everwrk),
         r_maritl=droplevels(r_maritl))
```